# When to use CLLocationManager or Google Maps myLocation

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the Google Maps SDK and am trying to figure out how to center my map on my current location.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.7127
                                                        longitude:-74.0059
                                                             zoom:12];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;
    mapView_.delegate = self;
```

}

I'm trying to set my current location from debug > set current location but all the locations are grayed out. I think the location may be hard coded in somewhere because when I click the current location arrow it takes me somewhere else. How can I choose a current location, center the map on that location and see the blue dot of my current location?

Answer (score 0):

use location manager

```
CLLocationManager* locationManager;
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

create gmap view

```
GMSCameraPosition* camera;
GMSMapView* mapView;
 camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                              longitude: locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
                                                   zoom:12];
mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Comment: [CLLocationManager  startUpdatingLocation]  - works not instantly, I think about 2-3 seconds